# Marionette.js Mediator ('global' commands vs app controller)

Tags: design-patterns, backbone.js, marionette, mediator

I am currently migrating a large backbone application over to Marionette and am curious as to the opinions on what is a better design for mediating activity between modules.

I have an Application that have several Modules where an action in one module might cause activity to happen in other modules.

Since these all are coupled to the Application I could simply use the Wreqr interface where:

**Module 1:**

```
someActivity: ->
   App.vent.trigger("skyFalling")
```

**Module 2:**

```
initialize: ->
   App.vent.on("skyFalling", @closeOrSomething)
```

**Module 3:**

```
initialize: ->
   App.vent.on("skyFalling", @blinkRapidly)
```

---

Or would it be better to trigger an event in Module1 where the Application (or a controller tied to the App) listens and then calls the 'closeOrSomething' and the 'blinkRapidly' functions directly on the modules (since the App is aware of all the modules that it is loading).

**Application:**

```
skyFallingEventHandler: ->
   Module2.closeOrSomething()
   Module3.blinkRapidly()
```

Comment: This is probably too opinionated a question. Both approaches will work and it is likely you could make a strong argument for either. This question is probably more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd chose a Mediator way with `app.vent.trigger()` and `app.vent.on()` and don't tie with the module's methods.
So that you're decoupling the modules and the application.
And just use an `Observer` + `Mediator` (pub/sub events via mediator object). And you don't need to care about method names and their calls.
If your module/class has been changed inside and don't need to react on some Application's event anymore, just disable the event handling (subscription) **inside** that **module** and you don't need to modify the code inside your `Application`. So that another engineer can just modify the module and don't need to modify an `Application` as well.